# I want limit 1 in inner join from one table within three tables and all records from first table

Tags: mysql, subquery

When I execute the following query;

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID,wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_date,wp_users.display_name 
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_users ON wp_posts.post_author=wp_users.ID 
INNER JOIN wp_comments ON wp_comments.comment_post_ID=wp_posts.ID 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT comment_author,comment_date,comment_content 
   FROM wp_comments  
   ORDER BY comment_date DESC LIMIT 1) b ON b.comment_post_ID=wp_posts.ID 
WHERE wp_posts.post_type='app-forum' 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

I get this error

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'b.comment_post_ID' in 'on clause'
```

Comment: you have to select `comment_post_ID` in `SELECT comment_author,
          comment_date,
          comment_content
   FROM wp_comments
   ORDER BY comment_date DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Consider providing proper create and insert statements together with a desired result

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery does not provide that column:

```
SELECT comment_author,comment_date,comment_content, **-- no comment_post_ID here**
FROM wp_comments  
ORDER BY comment_date DESC LIMIT 1) b
```

Think about `b` as an "ad-hoc table" (all columns generated by the subquery must have an explicit name).

Comment: thank you but now my query is executed but i didnt get the record from comments table 


SELECT wp_posts.ID,wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_date,wp_users.display_name FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_users ON wp_posts.post_author=wp_users.ID  INNER JOIN (SELECT comment_author,comment_post_ID,comment_date,comment_content FROM wp_comments ORDER BY comment_date DESC LIMIT 1) b ON b.comment_post_ID=wp_posts.ID WHERE wp_posts.post_type='app-forum' ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC

Answer (score -1):

You **have to select comment_post_ID** like this in your **inner join query**:

```
SELECT comment_author,
       comment_date,
       comment_content,
       comment_post_ID <-- here you have to select
FROM wp_comments
ORDER BY comment_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: SELECT wp_posts.ID,wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_date,wp_users.display_name FROM wp_posts

 INNER JOIN wp_users ON wp_posts.post_author=wp_users.ID  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT comment_author,comment_date,comment_content,comment_post_ID FROM wp_comments GROUP BY comment_post_ID ORDER BY comment_date DESC
) b ON b.comment_post_ID=wp_posts.ID WHERE wp_posts.post_type='app-forum' ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC


but now also i not get columns from comments table but i get columns from users and posts table only

Comment: @ShridharReddy what happened?